# How can I efficiently sample points in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I would like to use Earth Engine to sample raster data via points and save that information to a local file. I do this by creating a `FeatureCollection` of point geometries and then pass that structure to a `reduceRegions` call. I iterate over the result of `getInfo` to get the sampled raster data. However, the runtime of this function is much much slower than I would have expected. Is there any way to get runtime feedback about a job that is being processed on GEE, or a better way to asynchronously request jobs for a client side download?

This is a simplified, but functional, version of what I'm trying to do that takes 30ish seconds the first time I run it. My actual data includes thousands of points and the wait time makes me wonder if I've done something wrong.

```
import ee


def main():
    """Entry point."""
    ee.Initialize()

    pts = ee.FeatureCollection([
      ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-118.6010, 37.0777])),
      ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-118.5896, 37.0778])),
      ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-118.5842, 37.0805])),
      ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-118.5994, 37.0936])),
      ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-118.5861, 37.0567]))
    ])

    img = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_8DAY_NDVI").filterDate('1997-01-01', '2019-01-01')
    mean_img = img.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
    samples = mean_img.reduceRegions(**{
        'collection': pts,
        'scale': 30,
        'reducer': 'mean'}).getInfo()  #  <<< takes a long time to run! better way to do this?
    for sample in samples['features']:
        print(f"{sample['geometry']['coordinates']}, {sample['properties']['mean']}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: What it taking that much time is most likely getting the mean value for the stack of images. Consider the number of images it has to access in that time!

Answer (score 0):

Usually displaying the result takes ages (e.g.your print function). Try instead exporting the sampled table as a csv to your Google drive repo. This should speed up significantly your work. But it can still take quite some time!